# Regarding Facebook login integration

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am having a problem that I want to integrate the Facebook login in my website, so I have registered my website in Facebook and now if I am doing the Facebook login from my site it only permits me to login htrough Facebook, as I have registered the website in my Facebook account.

I know that this should not be the case. But what I am missing here, I am not able to get that. I want all the users will be able to login to my website through Facebook.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: yes, sure. Actually a part of my code is written in ColdFusion, though there are the basic javascripts also to call the Facebook Javascript SDK.

Comment: following is the code of the file ::

Comment: its a little difficult to paste the code here, I can send you the code via email if its OK with you.

Comment: I was asking you to post it not for my benefit but for others, they cant really help you without seeing what it is you are trying to do.  Why is it difficult to post the code? There shouldnt be that much of it for the actual facebook login itself.

Comment: I have got the solutions, actually I enabled the Sandbox security there in the Facebook for the website, thats why only I can login to the site through Facebook. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest that you check whether your app is still in **Sandbox** mode, but I see from your comment that you already figured this out :)